# .wav files in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, codecs

The default music player does not play .wav files. Please help me.

Comment: I was able to play .wav files on Rhythmbox but some I'd taken off of newer CDs (one was from 2013) wouldn't play. Rhythmbox told me I need a "demuxer" but it was unable to find Ubuntu software for this. (Sorry this isn't an actual solution but I thought it might contribute to resolving the problem.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use vlc or install codecs of it through internet...

Comment: very interesting

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have installed the restricted extra's package from the software centre, you may also find the following worth a read.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Comment: [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) uses [PCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) and to my knowledge there is no restriction (anymore) that prohibits using these without paying license fees or what ever applies. Suggesting to install restricted formats is misleading in this case.

Comment: you may be right NOW but in 2010.......

Comment: @LiveWireBT Other users report an error on Rhythmbox that says you need: "Advanced Streaming Format (ASF) demuxer" for certain wav files. Isn't this provided by the restricted extras package? I have looked around and people say that you need the restricted extras or the gstreamer ugly and bad plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to import music from CD.
Well,I was in the exactly same situation and was looking for the .wav codec for rhythmbox.
But I rethink it over at the first place, wav codec means uncompressed format. So I just copy the wav files in the cd folder and paste them to music directry for Rhythmbox.
After copy & paste, rename the files as you like.

Comment: [There is no WAV on a CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Book_%28audio_CD_standard%29#Data_access_from_computers). The software used in Ubuntu is actually aware that if a user inserts an Audio CD into a computer that the content should be made available to the user in the most convenient way, thus changing the format on the fly and presenting the whole CD as a bunch of WAV files. This kind of fast extraction may give inaccurate results due to scratches or how the drive generally accesses the CD. That's why EAC and [cdparanoia](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cdparanoia/) where made.

Answer (score 0):

The WAV file format isn't very practical for use in music players like Rhythmbox which want to present all the collected files in a library, because WAV doesn't support tagging (track name, artist, album name, genre, track number, etc.).

It's also very inefficient regarding diskspace because it's only using uncompressed PCM where [lossless codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_codec#Audio) like FLAC still deliver the *exact* same audio quality and usually provide tagging functionality.

To debunk the myth that only WAV delivers real CD quality:

- *Lossless* is what it says it is. It introduces no loss during encoding, contrary to overenthusiastic marketing for MP3 downloads with 128 kbits or Compact Cassettes. If *lossless* encoding would still cause loss, you wouldn't want to use ZIP or similar compression methods.
- WAV [isn't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Audio_CDs) what's stored on the CD. If you believe in never touching the signal stream that comes from the CD to retain maximum quality and your programs output is WAV you already "altered" the format. WAV is more comparable to a container format, the link to the Wikipedia article even offers MP3 in WAV format.

Comment: This is not the answer please give any suggestion's (if you have) to run a wav file on ubuntu??

Comment: As I said Rhythmbox wants to create a library out of tags. If you feed such music players files without such metadata they refuse or declare them as non-tagged rubbish, because you are not using the software the way intended. Use lossless formats like FLAC that support tag metadata or use another software like mplayer, VLC or whatever.